# Plotting more than one measurement per (categorical) group on one single plot in R

Tags: r, plot

Given the following dataframe I wish to plot the Q1,Q4 and mean value per each car brand type on one single plot (in this specific case 12 lines in total).

```
data <- structure(list(xBrand = c("Mercedes", "Mercedes", "Mercedes", 
"BMW", "BMW", "BMW", "Skoda", "Skoda", "Skoda", "Nissan", "Nissan", 
"Nissan"), X40 = c(70, 76, 56, 45, 47, 53, 57, 58, 84, 87, 91, 
99), X50 = c(73, 73, 69, 75, 76, 77, 79, 86, 74, 12, 19, 34), 
X60 = c(84, 84, 85, 84, 85, 89, 83, 84, 84, 85, 86, 87), 
X70 = c(130, 150, 120, 130, 134, 170, 170, 150, 158, 100, 
160, 130)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

I am sort of inclined to use the aggregate function to calculate each measurement per type which will give me three dataframes, convert each into a matrix and use the matplot function.

I wanted to ask if you believe it a sensible approach or whether I should steer into the direction of creating a list of dataframes first and work with lapply and ggplot2 next.

Thanks in advance
F

Comment: Is it `Q4` or `Q3`?

Comment: Q3 Rui, apologies it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1) %>% 
  rename(group = name) %>%
  group_by(xBrand, group) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value), 
            Q25 = quantile(value, 0.25), 
            Q75 = quantile(value, 0.75)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-(1:2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = xBrand, y = value, color = group, 
             group = interaction(name, group))) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = name)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Or an alternative using `geom_ribbon` :

```r
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1) %>% 
  rename(group = name) %>%
  group_by(xBrand, group) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value), 
            Q25 = quantile(value, 0.25), 
            Q75 = quantile(value, 0.75)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = xBrand, y = mean, color = group, group = group)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Q25, ymax = Q75, fill = group), 
              linetype = 2, alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]